# Solving the integral identity $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx. $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, integration, special-functions

We know that 0 is the additive identity and 1 is the multiplicative identity. In the same spirit let us define the integral identity as follows.

> **Definition**: Let $f(x)$ be integrable in $(a,b)$. If there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $f(x)g(x)$ is also integrable in $(a,b)$ and
>
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx $$
>
> then, $g(x)$ is the integral identity of $f(x)$ in the
>   interval $(a,b)$.

Trivially the number 1 is an integral identity in all intervals. Given below is an example for a non trivial integral identity in the interval $(0,\infty)$. We have for $a > 0$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\log\Big(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)dx  = \int_{0}^{\infty}\log\Big(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)\log\Big(\frac{a}{x}\Big)dx = \pi a.
$$

**Questions:**

1. Is there any reference to such functions in literature?
2. For what functions $f$ can we always find an integral identity in $(0,\infty)$ i.e how can we test if $f$ has an integral identity?
3. For what functions $f$ can we always find an integral identity in all arbitrary intervals $(a,b)$?
4. Can there be functions that have infinitely many integral identities in some intervals?

Answer (score 6):

An alternate way to say it: "$1-g$ is orthogonal to $f$"
$$
\int_a^b f(x)(1-g(x)) dx = 0
$$
Yes, there is extensive literature on orthogonal functions.